# Why is this promise chain not returning sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm trying to create a promise chain that returns the results in the order that they are called, as this is important for my application. However, despite a number of attempts I'm struggling as the output `resultArray` is coming back with some of the data points swapped, which screws up the downstream processing.  This is what I have currently (found on

```
Promise.all(data.map( (dataPoint) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    doSomething(dataPoint).then( (result) => {
      resultArray.push(result);
      resolve();
    });
  })
})).then( () => {
    res.status(201).json({"result": resultArray});
});
```

I have also tried the following pattern, but this just returns [] as the promise.all doesn't appear to wait for the promises to finish as intended:

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
data.forEach(dataPoint => {
  p = p.then( () => {
    getElevation(dataPoint, options).then( (result) => {
      resultArray.push(result);
    });
  });
});

Promise.all([p]).then( () => {
  res.status(201).json({"result": resultArray});
});
```

**UPDATE**

Although the question as written was answered, I now realise that the accepted answer does not wait for each promise to return before the next is launched.  It does map them so that the output is in the correct order, but I need each call to have a knowledge of the last - how do I achieve this succcinctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `forEach` & `[].push` if you want to get the data in order. Add the promises to the array and pass that array of promises to `Promise.all` that will keep the order for you.

Also your `let p = Promise.resolve()` line is not making any sense, it's just adding noise to your code.

Use `.map` to get an array of `getElevation` promises, and pass it to `Promise.all`, when it resolves the results will have the same order as `data` array.

```
const promises = data.map(dataPoint => getElevation(dataPoint, options));

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
  res.status(201).json({ result });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation - as I put in the update it is very useful if not exactly what I needed (but that's due to my poor question, not your good answr!)  However, would you mind explaining your point: "Also your let p = Promise.resolve() line is not making any sense"?? I have seen that pattern discussed before eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296452/javascript-promises-executing-promises-sequentially.  Why does it not make sense in this context?

Comment: Because you want results in order, passing a single promise to Promise.all won't achieve that. The pattern works for chaining, not for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) pattern if you want each promise to resolve completely before the next promise. This way every call has access to all the results of the previous calls.

```
async function run(options) {
  const results = [];
  for(let dataPoint of data) {
    const result = await getElevation(dataPoint, options);
    results.push(result);
  }
  return results;
}

run(options).then(result => {
  res.status(201).json({ result });
});
```